# Disable screen compatibility mode as a user

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screen-resolution

My phone (HTC Sensation) has recently been updated updated to Android 4.  An app that I already had installed now expands to fill the whole screen but looks very pixelated.  Is it possible to disable the auto screen resize for this application?

Looking at the SDK docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html), the developer of the app can disable it in the manifest file, but as that's not me I'm wondering how I can do it as a user of the app?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to contact the developer of the application via the contact email in its Google Play page.  The only compatibility option ICS has is a way to force accelerated rendering.  This can be found under the `Developer Options` section of the `Settings` app.  Based on your description, though, this probably won't resolve the scaling issue you have, besides possibly speeding the app up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will wait a couple of days and see if someone else knows a way (I'm not holding out much hope!) and then you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I used spareparts+ to set compatibility mode off, it really works.

but, in 4.2.1, spareparts+ seems not working.

I'm still finding some way to set compatibility mode off in 4.2.1

Comment: Please add a Google Play link. :)